# String literal inside struct - C

Tags: c

I need to encapsulate a literal string in a struct.  The code below won't compile, but hopefully illustrates what I would like to do?

```
struct my_struct
{
char* str = "string literal";
};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't initialize any members in a struct declaration. You have to initialize the struct when you create an instance of the struct.

```
struct my_struct
{
   char* str;
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
  struct my_struct foo = {"string literal"};
  ...
}
```

Since you want the  `str` member to refer to a string literal, you'd better make it a `const char *str` , as you can't modify string literals any way.

### Alternatively

#### Provide an initialization function

to initialize your struct to a known state every time.

```
struct my_struct
{
   const char* str;
   int bar;
};

void init_my_struct(strut my_struct *s)
{
   s->str = "string literal";
   s->bar = 0;
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
  struct my_struct foo;
  init_my_struct(&foo);
```

#### Or initializing it using the preprocessor:

```
struct my_struct
{
   const char* str;
   int bar;
}; 

#define MY_STRUCT_INITIALIZER {"string literal",0}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
 {
   struct my_struct foo = MY_STRUCT_INITALIZER;
```

#### Or copy from a known object:

```
struct my_struct
{
   const char* str;
   int bar;
};
const struct my_struct my_struct_init = {"string_literal",0};

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
   struct my_struct foo = my_struct_init;
```

Comment: Wow ! Good number of posssibilities. How about declaring it as a static variable ?

Comment: I tried but it isnot allowing me to do so. Shouldn't static variable be part of a `C Struct`. If yes, how to. http://ideone.com/NjkPJ

Comment: @Mahesh No, you can't do that in C. (But the code at ideone.com/NjkPJ  is ok in C++)

Comment: Yeah, I knew it is possible in `C++`. Another difference b/w C and C++ Struct. Thanks.

Comment: Great help.  Thank you for providing the various init options.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create an instance of the struct, and then set the `str` member. And if you plan to use string literals with it, you *really* should change it to `const char* str`.

```
struct my_struct
{
    const char* str;
};

int main() {
    struct my_struct s1;
    s1.str = "string literal";

    /* or */
    struct my_struct s2 = {"string literal"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
struct my_struct
{
    char* z;
};

// ...

struct my_struct s = {"string literal"};
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answers already given suggest, structure declaration and initialisation must be separate, and this must be applied consistently if it is required for all instances of `my_struct`.  C++ offers a better solution; if you could use C++ compilation, then this can be automated using a constructor as follows:

```
struct my_struct
{
    my_struct() : str("string literal"){}
    char* str ;
};
```

Then for all instances of `my_struct`, str will point to the literal constant `"string literal"` on instantiation.  Beware however that this is a non const pointer pointing to a const string.

Comment: I believe, the only answer which makes string literal encapsulated into structure, as was stated in question.

Comment: @Iurii true, but the question is tagged C not C++.  In 2011 you could get away with mentioning C++ in a C question on SO.  These days however I'd expect this answer to be heavily down voted.  C and C++ have deviated, but for some keeping them strictly separate seems to be non-negotiable.  It would at best make a comment today, and might still attract criticism.

Answer (score 1):

Direct initialization is not allowed. Instead what can be done is to make it a pointer and point it to your desirable string.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, but still, you have to use default initialized instance to init your new instances.

```
struct my_struct
{
    const char * str;
} ms_def {
    .str = "value"
};

int main()
{
    my_struct obj = ms_def;
    printf("%s\n", obj.str);
    return 0;
}
```